# Nested Ul LI hover hide show element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In nested ul li, I need to show edit and update link on li hover. I have jquery code that does it for me. Jquery works fine when i traverse from top to bottom but when I traverse from bottom to top, it does not work as desired and shows parent li's hidden div.

I want only hover li's span to show. Here is the required.

```
<ul id="tree">
<li><span>Mobile </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">Hey Hi, YOu
    caught me!!!</span>
    <ul class="subItem">
        <li><span>GSM Mobiles </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">Hey Hi,
            YOu caught me!!!</span> </li>
        <li><span>Smart Mobiles </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">Hey
            Hi, YOu caught me!!!</span>
            <ul class="subItem">
                <li><span>Android Mobiles </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">Hey
                    Hi, YOu caught me!!!</span> </li>
                <li><span>Sabian Mobiles </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">Hey
                    Hi, YOu caught me!!!</span> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Dual SIM Mobiles </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">
            Hey Hi, YOu caught me!!!</span> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>Watches </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">Hey Hi, YOu
    caught me!!!</span>
    <ul class="subItem">
        <li><span>Chronograph Watches </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">
            Hey Hi, YOu caught me!!!</span> </li>
        <li><span>Water Resistance </span>&nbsp; <span class="links" style="display: none;">
            Hey Hi, YOu caught me!!!</span> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery Code is here:

```
$('ul li').hover(function () {
            $("ul>li>span.links").hide();
            $(this).find("span.links").first().show();
        }, function () {

            $("ul>li>span.links").hide();
            $(this).find("span.links").first().hide();

        });
```

**Here is** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajanrawal/em79t/) **Link**

Answer (score 1):

When printing out $(this) I noticed that,
you are selecting both the inner and outer lists, be more specific in your selector:

```
$('#tree ul li').hover(function () {
   $("ul>li>span.links").hide();  

    $(this).find("span.links").first().show();
}, function () {
    $("ul>li>span.links").hide();
    $(this).find("span.links").first().hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried but does not work :( The code you mentioned then does not select first element.

Comment: That true, I hadn't fully tested the code I proposed , sorry should have mentioned that. But it's basically a selector problem. You are selecting your inner and outer lists. 
I've updated your jsfiddle and added level1 class attribute so the event will only be fired on those li elements who have a level1 class attribute. Again I have only tested this for the first item. You should be able to figure things out from there.

Comment: Thank you jonas, but that is what i want. I want to know how can I improve my js code. :)